# Totally real points on curves

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective (geometrically integral) curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ with genus $g \geq 3$.  Suppose that $X(\mathbb{R}) \neq \emptyset$.  Does $X$ have a point defined over a totally real field?

Comment: This is a theorem of L. Moret-Bailly. See "Groupes de Picard et problemes de Skolem I, II", *Ann. Sci. ENS* Ser. 4, 1989. It does not require your geometric restrictions on $X$.

Comment: For an exposition of the proof I can also refer you to Brian Conrad's "Overview of Moret-Bailly's theorem on global points."

Comment: The document to which Dimitrov refers is at this link: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/vigregroup/vigre05/mb.pdf